# LED Circuit - Resistor calculation

Tags: led, resistors, circuit-design

If I have an [LED such as this](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Wurth-Elektronik/156120SS82500?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvyj6n1w4pZD6eAxfjFR14Ds57fge2pz2jRCH9E81OVKA%3D%3D)

It has a forward current of 20mA
It has a forward voltage of 2V.

If my supply is 3.3v, am I correct in saying I would need a resistor value of 65 Ohms.

My calculation is :

```
R=V/I
R=1.3/0.02
R=65
```

Comment: Yes that is correct, where V= supply voltage  - diode forward voltage = 3.3-2.0 = 1.3

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your calculation is correct.

68 Ω is the nearest E12 value and you won't detect any difference using that.

Answer (score -1):

The answer needs to include the voltage drop across any transistor used to switch current on and off as well.

(Vs - Vf - Vce)/current desired = resistor

(3.3V - 2V - 0.7V)/.02A = 30 ohm if you used say an NPN transistor with Vce of 0.7V.

If using a MOSFET, then work Rds of the MOSFET into the equation instead. Altho not many MOSFETs will switch with a 3.3V system, so NPN is better in that case.

Comment: Another commentless downvote, how helpful is that?